# Loading and processing a file using Stream

Tags: java, file, java-8, text-files, java-stream

I have a task to do.  Load a text file with multiple lines, print the text on the console, convert text to uppercase, and save it to another text file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "src/PISMENA.txt";
    Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
    stream.map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I want to do it as simple as possible so I tried to used Stream form java 8. I do not know how to continue with that. One option is to convert Stream to List and work with that, but it removes lines and whole text is on one line. What are my options how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to file will leave to you:)

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
   .peek(System.out::println)
   .map(String::toUpperCase)
   .forEach(line-> //*add to file*//)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
stream.map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(output::println);

// and don't forget to close
stream.close();
output.close();
```